# Creating a POPUP style window

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I have an answer regarding creation of the POPUP style window. The thing that do really bothers me is the `hWndParent` parameter. The docs says:

> This parameter is optional for pop-up windows

My question is how does the POPUP window created with the `hWndParent` parameter set just to `NULL` behaves? Does it belong to the desktop itself? How is it z-ordered/displayed on the screen? Does it spwan above all other windows or just only over the desktop such that other windows covers it?

Comment: An unowned popup window is a top-level window, and follows the normal rules for top-level windows.

Comment: How do you expect windows with `WS_POPUP` to differ in behavior from those with `WS_OVERLAPPED`? Are you perhaps confusing "popup" windows with dialog windows, or with modal windows in general?

Comment: The difference between POPUP and OVERLAPPED windows used to be major prior to Windows 3.0. Said differently is has been mostly cosmetic for little more than 30 years...

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you could refer to the Doc: [Window Features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-features)

A pop-up window is a special type of overlapped window used for dialog boxes, message boxes, and other temporary windows that appear outside an application's main window. Title bars are optional for pop-up windows; otherwise, pop-up windows are the same as overlapped windows of the WS_OVERLAPPED style.

An overlapped window is a top-level window (non-child window) that has a title bar, border, and client area; it is meant to serve as an application's main window.

Comment: @darek_911 Have you got any updates? If your case has been solved, please help to mark answers. If not, just feel free to contact us. Your understanding and cooperation will be grateful.